# Backbone model undefined attributed in defaults and scope

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

It seems that if a backbone model does not have a default set for an attribute that gets referenced in a template, that it looks in the global scope? (EDIT: I'm using Marionette and Underscore as well)

I have a template which contains the following content:

```
<td><@= ((location !== null)?location:'N/A') @></td>
```

When this gets rendered it displays the URL for the page, including the hash. I'm assuming it's displaying location from the global namespace (`Window.location.toString()`). This occurs when the incoming JSON string that populates the model does not have the location attribute defined and the model does not have a default set.

If incoming data contains a location property in the key/value pairs, it displays the value just fine.

If the incoming data does not contain the property, but there's a default set on the model:

```
myModel = io.models.BaseModel.extend({
    defaults: {
        location:null,...
```

Then it displays "N/A" as would be expected.

I guess my question is, is this how backbone rolls — If the property is undefined on the model, does it then look into other scopes? Or is this have to do with how location is evaluated when the template is rendered?

I'd really like to understand what is happening so I have a better idea of how I might need to change things to prevent scope pollution in the most correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I havent ever seen backbone models accessing the global scope. Anyway, this does not seem to be connected to backbone, which to be precise, does not come with a templating engine. Templates are normally handled by underscore, which I also used in my projects. There I suppose you are passing the model attributes like that:

```
myModel.toJSON();
```

This will return an object containing all the attribute key/value pairs. They then are accessible in the template as if they have been defined as variables. Underscore does not know about the model, it will just access the variables passed to it. If there is no variable called "location", it will take it from the global object "window". This is the normal behaviour of javascript.

Try passing the model as is to underscore and use myModel.get("location") instead.

Comment: Not quite. The problem is that compiled Underscore templates use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to make the passed object look like a scope and then `with` goes up to `window` when resolving things. There are `_.template` options to suppress the use of `with`. And passing whole models to a template is generally considered to be a bad idea.

Comment: Daniel — Sorry, I'm using Underscore. I updated my question, but it must have been at the same time you were answering.

Comment: @muistooshort is too short — That sounds pretty plausible and would make sense. Thanks for the tip on the template options on Underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using the `variable` template option as described by @muistooshort, and using the defined namespace in the template.

```
_.templateSettings = {
    variable: "_tdata"
};
```

-

```
<td><@= ((location !== null)?_tdata.location:'N/A') @></td>
```

It was kind of a pain to update all of the templates, but worked fine in the end. Seems like there should have be an easier implementation, like a simple flag in the underscore template settings.